# SUSE SLES 11: zypper: Ignore dependency in scripted setup

Tags: linux, package-management, suse, zypper

I have an issue here, trying to install libopenssl-devel on a SuSE box. The installation is purely from DVD (no online updates involved).

```
$ sudo zypper install libopenssl-devel
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

Problem: nothing provides libopenssl0_9_8 = 0.9.8h needed by libopenssl-devel-0.9.8h-30.11.x86_64
 Solution 1: do not install libopenssl-devel-0.9.8h-30.11.x86_64
 Solution 2: break libopenssl-devel-0.9.8h-30.11.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies

Choose from above solutions by number or cancel [1/2/c] (c):
```

Interactively, I would select option 2 (ignore dependencies), as the installed version of libopenssl is 0.9.8j, and the difference does not matter for my purposes. (No, really, it doesn't.)

The problem is that I would like to run the installation from within a script (Vagrant provider script), so...

**How do I tell zypper to ignore a dependency, non-interactively?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
zypper -n install --force package
```

`-n` = non interactive
`--force` force install package

Comment: Figured that out myself and forgot about this question. :-D Have a checkmark!